# If $f$ in $H(G)$ can be approximated by rational functions which only have poles at $0$ and infinity, then $C_\infty \setminus G$ has $2$ components

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from a past exam:

> Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a region such that $0 \not \in G$ and $G$ is not simply connected. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $C_\infty \setminus G$ has precisely two components $F_0$, $F_\infty$ such the $0 \in F_0$, $\infty \in F_\infty$.
>
> (ii) Every $f \in H(G)$ can be approximated by rational functions with poles only in $\{0, \infty\}$.

I can prove one direction using Runge's theorem, but I'm not sure how to prove the other direction ((ii) $\implies$ (i)). I know that $C_\infty \setminus G$  must have at least two components because $G$ is not simply connected, and that if $G$ was bounded, then $C_{\infty} \setminus G$ would have exactly one unbounded component, but I am not sure how to relate the conditions in (ii) to those in (i).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It's important to also MathJax the titles of your posts, just a heads up. A good-looking (and descriptive, but yours was already descriptive) title is always a plus.